# Telegram bot на python. Ошибка связана с "выключение бота "

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Ребята, я вот к примеру не в первый раз сталкиваюсь с проблемой, но решения так и не нашел. К примеру того же самого телеграм бота, написал на python, всё работает как надо, свои функции выполняет, но через некоторое время бездействия прога просто не работает и выдает ошибку

> ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост
>   принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

такое было и с хоть и хреновым но голосовым ассистентом(тоже python), кто знает что не так?

Comment: Возможно вы сможете отправить ошибку?

Comment: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

Comment: Дело скорее в блокировке Telegram на территории Российской Федерации. Воспользуйтесь VPN и повторите попытку подключения, а также желательно проверьте подключение к интернету.

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, нигде не могу найти ответ! И телеграм уже разблокирован и всё равно я пробовал через VPN итог один: через мин 10-15 бездействия прога отрубается и выдаёт ту же самую ошибку.

Comment: скорее всего порты блочит что-то или связь нестабильная